# Cron Job at random Time

Tags: node.js, cron

I am having a trouble in calling cron job at random time, I want to call function on every month but on a random day from 1st to 20th. I want to do this using node js.

```
let month = 11; 
let day = 6;
cron.schedule(`0 0 ${day} ${month} *`, () => {
myFunction();
if(month == 12) {
month = 1;
}else {
month++;
}
const min = 1;
const max = 20;
const day = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
console.log(day);
});`
```

This is my code snippet, when I tested it on minute like I am passing the minute at which I want to call cron but it is running only 1 time, can someone help me out with this, thanks in advance